# how to shutdown the ubuntu machine in another way?

Tags: google-chrome, shutdown

I have a requirement that need to shutdown the ubuntu machine when user log out or close google chrome,could anyone give me an better idea and some details on how to do this?

I think I should write a shell script to monitor certain processes and run this script as cron job.

Thanks.

Comment: That can be done. How is chrome started ? via script ? Also, where that requirements come from ?

Comment: @Serg,chrome can be started from either command line or GUI,my company want to make a ubuntu desktop only for web-browsering.Can you give me more details?

Comment: So the user logs in , and they start chrome by themselves. Right ?   And yes, you will have to have scripts, but as far as I understand, it probably will require having two scripts. One will have to watch for Chrome to be closed, the other for logout event.

Comment: Just to let you know , I'm working on the scripts right now. I'll post an answer once i get at least 75% of it working.

Comment: @Serg,thank you very much.I will wait for your message.

Answer (score 2):

## Contents:

1. General ideas
2. Script Source
3. Additional suggestions

#### 1. General ideas:

It is possible to inhibit logout from Unity or Gnome session via `dbus` - an interprocess communication bus which allows executing certain actions as root on behalf of regular user. In my tests, it seems that log out is forceful in Unity; this means inhibit will only last a few seconds, but it is enough for us to run a shutdown command. The inhibit lock is also broken once user clicks "Log Out" option in the log-out dialog

[image]

The script below does exactly that. It runs two functions simultaneously. One function waits for Chrome to appear and then for Chrome processes to be gone and shutdown. The other function , inhibits
 the logout until the lock is broken , and once the lock is broken it calls shutdown function.

This script is meant to be added as startup application. Since you must use it for each user in your company, I suggest you place the `.desktop` file for this code into `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder. That way it will be running for all users automatically

#### 2. Script source

It is also available on [GitHub as gist](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/5a1f488d3f05d370ecef04401619429d)

`/usr/bin/inhibit_logout.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#    Author: Serg Kolo,<1047481448@qq.com>
#    Date: September 28, 2016
#    Purpose: Monitoring script that shutsdown
#             system if logout occurs or chrome exits
#    Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/828524/295286

from gi.repository import Gdk
import dbus
import os
import threading
import subprocess

def get_dbus(bus_type,obj,path,interface,method,*argv):

    if bus_type == "session":
        bus = dbus.SessionBus() 
    if bus_type == "system":
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    proxy = bus.get_object(obj,path)
    method = proxy.get_dbus_method(method,interface)
    if argv:
        return method(*argv)
    else:
        return method()  

def shutdown():
    ''' Wrapper for dbus Shutdown method '''
    get_dbus('session',
             'com.canonical.Unity', 
             '/com/canonical/Unity/Session', 
             'com.canonical.Unity.Session',
             'Shutdown',None)

def is_inhibited():
    ''' wrapper for IsInhibited dbus method'''
    return get_dbus('session',
             'org.gnome.SessionManager', 
             '/org/gnome/SessionManager', 
             'org.gnome.SessionManager',
             'IsInhibited',
             1)

def is_chrome_running():
    '''checks output of pgrep for
       any chrome processes'''
    try:
         null=open(os.devnull,'w')
         subprocess.check_call(['pgrep','-f','chrome'],stdout=null,stderr=null)    
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def inhibit_logout():
    ''' Inhibits log out temporarily so that we have
    enough time to shutdown '''

    # pretend we are root window
    # and inhibit logout on our behalf
    root_window_xid = int(Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_root_window().get_xid())
    get_dbus('session',
             'org.gnome.SessionManager',
             '/org/gnome/SessionManager',
             'org.gnome.SessionManager',
             'Inhibit', 
             'root_window',
             root_window_xid, 
             'TEST REASON', 
             1)

    # once the inhibitor is removed, shutdown
    while is_inhibited():
       pass
    shutdown()    

def capture_chrome():
    # wait for chrome to start
    while not is_chrome_running():
       pass

    # start waiting till it exits
    while is_chrome_running():
       pass

    # once chrome exits, shutdown
    shutdown()

def main():
    ''' program entry point'''
    threading.Thread(target=inhibit_logout).start()     
    threading.Thread(target=capture_chrome).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

`/etc/xdg/autostart/inhibit_logout.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Logout Inhibitor
Exec=/usr/bin/inhibit_logout.py
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Terminal=false
```

#### 3. Additional suggestion:

To prevent user from explicitly loging out and breaking the inhibitor lock, use

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-menuitem true
```

This will remove logout option, but won't remove Ctrl+Alt+Del shortcut for logout. Consider removing that one as well