# Run script when user logged out; Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, scripts, lightdm, automation, logout

In Ubuntu 12.04 I used LightDM config parameter `session-cleanup-script` to run a script when a user logs out.

In Ubuntu 16.04 this script is also fired when a user types the wrong username or password. So the user wasn't even logged in.

How can I run a script in Ubuntu 16.04 only if a user logs out?

**EDIT:**

OK, I thought this is an easy one. But it seems to be more complex. I use this on public terminal PCs. At first LightDM is not loaded. The user has to choose between Windows (via VMware View), Ubuntu and a Kiosk browser. He clicks a specific button to login to Ubuntu. Now LightDM (and some other stuff) gets started. When the user logs out LightDM gets stopped from the script in `session-cleanup-script`.

I think the Upstart/systemd method wont work as I need some environment variables like `$USER` and `$HOME`, right?.

The DBus signal seems to fire when the user wants to logout. I need a event when the user already is logged out to clean some things.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/517633/602680) and its answer could be useful.

Comment: @OwenHines: Upstart is pretty much dead (or at least very much legacy and deprecated) in Xenial.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Oh, sorry. Good to know.

Comment: A good way to do it using systemd instead of lightdm is outlined in this perma-linked comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/796157/610274

Comment: Thanks for your comments and great hints. I've added more details to my question. Thought it would be easier.

Comment: If the script  doesn't need to run long time, you could use session inhibitors, see my answer here : http://askubuntu.com/q/828524/295286

Comment: ` I need a event when the user already is logged out` , well put a delay with `sleep` , or fire up a script that will keep looking at output of `who` command to see when username disappears form the list of logged in users.

Comment: I also tried pam-script now. But when *ses_close is called for Unity session  the username is lightdm and not the real user which was logged in.